# cannot access viewBinding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm now using viewBinding with Kotlin.

here is my build.gradle
[image: build.gradle]

enable ViewBinding and has auto import ViewBinding dependency.

but Android Studio still shows error like this
[image: Android Studio Error]

but I can build and run with no problem.

and if I add viewBinding in dependencies, then the error is gone.

Does anyone know why?

UPDATE:

I know why. I'm using AndroidX, and the IDE says can not access 'android.viewbinding.ViewBinding', but my dependency is AndroidX, it is 'androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding', package name changed.

SOLUTION:
add android.useAndroidX=true to project gradle.properties file.

global gradle.properties setting does not work, don't know why.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: What is your android gradle plugin version?

Comment: @Bek I'm awayls use the last version. thanks for comment, I know why, see my update.

Comment: Try to add `android.useAndroidX=true` to `gradle.properties` file then invalidate cache restart

Comment: @Bek It is work after I add android.useAndroidX=true to project  gradle.properties file.  But it already added in global gradle.properties file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facing same issue exact error yesterday. Solution work for me is

- Step 1- Remove .Idea Folder
- Step 2- Close android studio
- Step 3- Reopen android studio with same project path (This will genarate new
  .Idea folder)

and Error is gone

Making sure

1. android.useAndroidX=true.  inside gradle.properties file
2. inside app build.gradle

> ```
>  buildFeatures {
>        viewBinding true
>  }
> ```

3. Always Use folder structure with samll case latter only class name is allowed to be Uppercase
4. If you are using any Copyright-Comment at top of xml or Layout tag without variable tag or we can say without any data then remove that and try to clean/rebuild project

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem or did I? I found that the find in Android Studio was including old projects which did have kotlinx.android.synthetic imports. Could not find out how this occurred so closed studio and rm -rf the .idea. Not only did it cure the problem but speed it back up to a usable state. (Still not as good as VS Code) Hope it helps someone and ask an adult before deleting .idea in your project.

Comment: Yes, closed Android Studio then deleted the ".idea" folder solved this issue. Thank you

Comment: it work for me as well :)

Answer (score 1):

For me the error fixed when I changed the viewBinding build option to true in the module-level build.gradle file from Groovy mode to Kotlin mode, as shown below :

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

source : [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the problem may lie in the fact that you're using both `dataBinding` and `viewBinding`. Try removing one of them then rebuild your Android Studio project.

Comment: I know why, see my update.  thanks for anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding in build.gradle

```
plugins{
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android{
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but my same problem got solved by removing below line from gradle.properties(project properties)

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and this is the solution I got

1. go to the project gradle.properties
2. delete the android.useAndroidX=true line (in my enviroment this is set by default)
3. Sync gradle
4. add the deleted line again
5. Sync again

I noticed that the gradle has a comment that said that this setting was a duplicate
so im guessing there was some kind of internal conflict

Used environment:

- Android Studio Flamingo|2022.1 Patch 1
- Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, built on April 20, 2023