# Android ViewBinding error in the inflate-method - missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

After removing the existing `DataBinding` from the project, I also wanted to get rid of the `kotlinx.android.synthetic` and replace it with `ViewBinding`.

However, after enabling `ViewBinding` in my project, I'm still not able to do a proper setup.

Trying to invoke the `ViewBinding` into my `MainActivity` or in one of my fragments I get the following error in the `inflate` method:

```
Cannot access 'no_name_in_PSI_...' which is a supertype of 'com.example.projectname.databinding.ActivityMainBinding'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

For example:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<SharedViewModel>() {
      private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
      ...
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
      }
}
```

[image]

My `build.gradle (:app)` is properly set up:

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
android {
  ...
  buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

I've used `ViewBinding` in another project of mine and it worked out of the box. Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have this `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` in root tag of your activity_main.xml file?

Comment: @JeelVankhede thank you so much for your quick response. I've added this tag into the `activity_main.xml` file. The error dissapeared, but I'm still facing the same issue in the fragments where I actually need to use the `ViewBinding`.

Comment: That's weird because this tag basically tells view binding extension whether to generate bindings for specific file or not. May be cleaning-rebuilding project helps..

Comment: I've cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated caches, restarted, deleted the `idea` folder, did almost everything, but still it's not working.

Comment: I faced the same issue a few days back, try using the DataBindingUtil class to do the inflation, that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I added the layout tag in my xml files and that's not correct. Layout tag is for data binding but here we are only enabling view binding feature. That's why you are getting that error. Just remove the layout tag.
Edit- I am elaborating this answer since it is not clear.
Remove the  tag from your XML file.
Reason- As stated in android data binding documentation,  is used when "dataBinding" is enabled. But here you have enabled "viewBinding" for which  should not be used in XML file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found this answer correct. Just remove the ``<layout></layout>`` tag in your xml, because that is the configuration for data binding, not view binding.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem yesterday. Only new update of android studio to version was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .idea folder

- Step 1- Remove .Idea Folder
- Step 2- Close android studio
- Step 3- Reopen android studio with same project path (This will genarate new
  .Idea folder)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036526/4741746